# Can I see who voted on my posts? Can anyone?

Tags: support, voting

Is there a way to see who upvoted our questions, answers, or comments? If there isn't, is there a reason that this is not available?

Comment: Me has upvoted you [here](http://superuser.com/questions/525486/windows-7-boot-option-missing-after-installing-windows-xp/525490#525490) :P

Comment: (: Why, thank-you :)

Comment: I am sure EasyBCD will do the job. Doesn't it? Now we are very off-topic :)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This [has been discussed before](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/27534/see-who-is-upvoting-downvoting-my-question-answer) on Meta Stack Overflow.

Essentially, no. You cannot see who voted for you or anybody else, and nor can the moderators. Only Stack Exchange employees with direct database access can see individual votes.

Voting is specifically designed to be anonymous.